# Taking log of "n" many times consecutively, while n goes to infinity

Tags: limits, logarithms

Let us define $$\log^{(i)}{n}=\log{(\log^{(i-1)}{n})}$$
with this condition:
$$i\ge{0}:\log^{(i)}{n}\le1$$
i.e. repeated application of the log function. 
I wonder what is the result of following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{i\to\infty}{\log^{(i)}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log\log\log\cdots\log{n}}$$
I feel like the answer would be a constant number like $C$, is it correct?

---

Conclusion: the way the problem is composed, it is not possible to have repeated application of $\log$ function.

Comment: First of all, when you have: $$\ln^{\left(\text{n}\right)}\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{d}^\text{n}}{\text{d}x^\text{n}}\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)$$ And I do not think that you mean that. Second do not use $i$, because it is confusing with $i^2=-1$

Comment: I don't think your second equality is correct. You cannot remove one of the $\lim$'s from the equation.

Comment: Since $0 < \log\log 4 < 1$, you have $\log\log\log 4 < 0$ and then there's a problem with the fourth term in your sequence, "$\log\log\log\log 4$" does not exist (in $\mathbb{R}$) (and further terms).

Comment: The condition you've added doesn't help. If $\log^{(i)}n \leq 1$, then $\log^{(i+1)}n = \log(\log^{(i)}n) \leq 0$, so $\log^{(i+2)}n$ is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote it, the limit does not exist, because for every $n$, there exists some $i$ such that $\log^{(i)}(n) \leq 0$, and thus $\log^{(i+1)}(n)$ does not exist.

Comment: Right, actually there is a condition which I missed, now I add the condition to the post

Comment: But I'm not sure if the condition makes sense...

Comment: @user4838962 The condition doesn't really make sense. It's not true that $\log^{(i)} n \leq 1$ if $i\leq 0$. For example, if $i=1$ and $n=10000$, then the inequality is false.

Comment: I looked at the problem text again, the problem is composed like this: assume there is a function $T(n)$:
$$T(n)=\log{\log^{*}{n}}$$
Where:
$$\log^{*}{n}=\min\{i\ge{0}:\log^{(i)}{n}\le1\}$$
and:
$$\log^{(i)}{n}=\log{(\log^{(i-1)}{n})}$$
what is the result of:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{T(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log{\log^{*}{n}}}=?$$

Comment: @user4838962 You are now basically asking a whole new question. I recommend you ask another question (and add a link to this one) with the revised content.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a new question with more accurate details [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2196455/426894)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean
$$
f(x) = \ln(x)
$$
and ponder about the iteration
$$
x_{n+1} = f(x_n) \quad (n \in \mathbb{N})
$$
for some starting value $x_0$. As the graph of $\ln$ does not intersect the graph of the identity function, there is no fixed point
$$
x^* = f(x^*)
$$
which would exist if $\lim x_n$ existed.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into this question somewhere, I'm not sure what had in his mind the one who designed this question